# Best way to code a javascript web game considering variables and portability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm coding a basic game in HTML/javascript/CSS and I'm just after some advice on best practice/best way to do it.

I only have a basic knowledge of javascript but it seems easy enough and there's nothing too fancy required in my game.

The game will be relatively simple in that it's mainly menu/screen based; there will be a main menu which the user navigates from, which will open the required screen for them to make in game purchases etc, before returning to the main menu screen.

What I'm trying to work out is whether I should do it as just one page, that dynamically changes as the user makes their choices, or several pages for each of the menu items. The second sounds much 'cleaner' in terms of code and layout, but then I have to pass variables across to each page. Some of this information needs to be secure, so I'm thinking of using HTML5's localStorage or sessionStorage. It seems to work well in Chrome but IE8 doesn't seem to like it during my offline testing, apparently you need to have the file uploaded as it's 'domain' based? I thought the whole 'local' meant it could be done locally!

What I also need to consider is that in the future I'd like to convert this to a Facebook or even mobile app. I believe there are some 'wrappers' available and that you can port it across... is the fact that I'm planning on using multiple pages/localStorage going to affect future portability? Is there another way I should be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Post some relevant code, if you want your question to be considered.

Comment: 1 page with dynamically changing content is the best way. Yes, you have to run your game from an http server (what you meant by uploading it) to use localStorage and other features like XHR. At this early stage in learning game development it might be a good idea for you to consult some good books on HTML5 game development so that you have a good roadmap of the technology and skills you'll need to know.

Comment: Thanks guys, think I'll do a bit more reading.

Comment: Im in the middle of the same problem. Did you manage to sort this problem out ? Hopefully youre still around :L

Answer (score 0):

I have create a few HTML5 Javascript games, I for one did not purchase any books as you can usually find some good stuff out there on the web, so just do some google searchs for HTML5 canvas game or Javascript Html Game.

The best thing to try and keep in mind is OOP (Object-oriented programming), this really helped me out create my simple games as it just keeps a nice pattern.

But basically what I did was just dive straight in and just code. A good editor is Sublime.

Sorry I couldn't off been much help however, if you take a look at a game I created and view the source files, you may get a good understanding of how to create a game :)

http://canvascode.co.uk/Projects/SpaceDestroyer/spacedestroyer.html

Also you could always pick up Unity which is portable for nearly every system there is :)